# Issue with INNER JOIN and UNION

Tags: php, mysql

The query below returns this error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in xxx.php on line 21. 
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in xxx.php on line 24

The query only seems to work when I remove the 'userID' column from both SELECT statements. Does this have anything to do with the fact that i'm using 'userID' for my INNER JOIN? How can I fix this issue? Thanks in Advance.

QUERY;

```
$sql = "SELECT parentID, userID, Rating, Comment, upvote_count, Time FROM     ratings_n_comments
        INNER JOIN user_details
        ON ratings_n_comments.userID=user_details.UserID 
        WHERE ratings_n_comments.mID= '".$mID."'    
        UNION
        SELECT parentID, userID, Rating, Comment, upvote_count, Time FROM replys_to_comments
        INNER JOIN user_details
        ON replys_to_comments.userID=user_details.UserID 
        WHERE replys_to_comments.mID= '".$mID."'";
```

Comment: please dont use `'".$mID."'` :(

Comment: I think userID is in both of 2 table so you need to specific table in select
Example: SELECT parentID, user_details .userID, ....

Comment: I don't think there is issue in query looking at you `warnings` and `error`. Methods which you using for executing the result is having issue. **Note:You should use alias for userID while selecting**

Answer (score 0):

Table  user_details and ratings_n_comments have same column name userID, because of ambiguity it will not display the result. so, use  user_details.userID or 
ratings_n_comments.userID in select statement like i am using below

```
"SELECT parentID, user_details.userID, Rating, Comment, upvote_count, Time FROM     ratings_n_comments
        INNER JOIN user_details
        ON ratings_n_comments.userID=user_details.UserID 
        WHERE ratings_n_comments.mID= '".$mID."'    
        UNION
        SELECT parentID, user_details.userID, Rating, Comment, upvote_count, Time FROM replys_to_comments
        INNER JOIN user_details
        ON replys_to_comments.userID=user_details.UserID 
        WHERE replys_to_comments.mID= '".$mID."'";
```